# (function) variable: Unbound

Tags: python-3.x, function, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm writing a program in which the user plays a number guessing game with the computer. The computer chooses it's number using random. I seem to be running into this error after the user inputs their number. Any idea why? The variable seems to be fine above in the if statement.

```py
import random

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
restart = 'Y'
stop = 'N'

print("Can you test your luck against the computer?\n Guess the number the computer is thinking, and you win!")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

def game():
    player_choice = int(input("Please chose a number: "))
    computer_choice = random.randint(0, 5)
    if player_choice == computer_choice:
        player_score += 1
        print("You win!\nComputer Score: ",computer_score," Player Score: ",player_score)
    elif player_choice != computer_choice:
        computer_choice += 1
        print("Computer wins...\nComputer Score: ",computer_score," Player Score: ",player_score)
```

Here's the terminal window as well.
[image]

Comment: The `player_score` inside `game()` is a *local variable* by default (since the function contains an assignment to that name), completely unrelated to the global variable you initialized outside the function.  Either move the initialization into the function (assuming that all uses of the variable are within a single call to `game()`), or add `global player_score` in the function to allow access to the outer variable.

Comment: For the future: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `player_score` global.

```py
import random

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
restart = 'Y'
stop = 'N'

print("Can you test your luck against the computer?\n Guess the number the computer is thinking, and you win!")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

def game():
    global player_choice
    player_choice = int(input("Please chose a number: "))
    computer_choice = random.randint(0, 5)
    if player_choice == computer_choice:
        player_score += 1
        print("You win!\nComputer Score: ",computer_score," Player Score: ",player_score)
    elif player_choice != computer_choice:
        computer_choice += 1
        print("Computer wins...\nComputer Score: ",computer_score," Player Score: ",player_score)
```

[Helpful link](https://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/local-variables.html#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20global%20statement,function%20without%20the%20global%20statement.)

Comment: This worked. I needed to make both player_score and computer_score global in order for it to work

Comment: @AndreiDalton93 oh yes, sorry for overlooking making `computer_score` global. Good to know that it worked! :)